# Generate Hamiltonian path with obstacles

Tags: graphs

I want to make some Hamiltonian paths with obstacles in a grid that are hard to find
It's for a game that I want to create, which consists of passing from all the cases of the grid without passing from the same one twice, and there is a start and an ending case, and the map "Grid" may have some obstacles.

- The cases would be the vertices,
- The player may move UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT "Existing Edges"
- Obstacles "Absent vertex and edge leading to this case"

My problem is, how can I generate the levels from easy paths to the hardest

PS : I've been searching the net about my problem and I didn't seem to find any solution

Comment: How large are these levels, i.e., how many vertices?

Comment: We talking about grids/maps, the game would have so many maps representing the levels, up to 100 level or even more... and starting of 4*4 grid map in early levels, to 15*15 or 15*20 in the advanced one... assuming each case is a vertex : in early levels up to 16 vertices, 'cause the map would have some obstacles... same goes for latter levels